# Can't get reactive form validations to work using FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I'm trying to validate my forms using an array of FormGroups.

It was working before adding an array of FormGroups (material stepper validation purposes).

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="fullName" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.formArray.controls['fullName'].errors?.required">Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="shortName" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.formArray.controls['shortName'].errors?.required">Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS:

```
get formArray(): AbstractControl | null { return this.formGroup.get('formArray'); }

this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    formArray: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({ fullName: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
        this.fb.group({ shortName: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
    ])
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That just looks strange... usually when we have a form array, it contains formgroups with the same form controls. Why would you need formarray and nested formgroups? Why not just form controls?

Comment: This way I'm able to work with linear angular's material steppers without creating extra FormGroups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your array here is an array of groups and you need to treat it as such, btw, this is a weird way to do this...

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <ng-container formArrayName="formArray">
    <mat-form-field formGroupName="1">
        <input matInput formControlName="fullName" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.formArray.controls[1].controls['fullName'].errors?.required">Required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field formGroupName="2">
        <input matInput formControlName="shortName" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.formArray.controls[2].controls['shortName'].errors?.required">Required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

so what I've added is a container referencing the form array name and then directives letting it know the formGroupName (which is the index in the case of a FormArray) for each control in the array. I've also added a step in your validation check where I access the formarray control index.  I'm not sure at all why you need or would want this structure, but this will work now.